# Azure SQL Connection Delay

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a .NET Core Azure Functions App hosted on an App Service plan. The plan is dedicated with isolated pricing tier. The Functions app has `Always On` setting turned on. For some reason, the app is having issues connecting to Azure SQL database. The database is running on same region as the Functions app and has Business Critical pricing tier.

I am seeing in Application Insights that API calls are taking seconds to finish because the codepath is busy waiting to get an SQL connection. The actual database operations finish within milliseconds.

I have ran the app locally with database connection strings set to the Azure SQL databases and saw no delay at all. Each requests finished within milliseconds. Then I created a new Azure Functions app outside existing App Service Environment with a dedicated App Service plan. The result is the same, no delay at all.

### Question

Has anyone faced this type of issue before or has any idea about what the problem may be? Is there any network gateway used by Azure App Service Environment that is maybe causing this issue?

P.S. There are other apps on the App Service Environment which face this issue too, but on less amount of requests.

Comment: Really hard to help without seeing the code. My guess is that you're not properly disposing the connection / working with a connection pool. Another possible reason can be the usage of synchronous operation that are blocking the connections

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I thought so too at first. So I checked the database calls and didn't find anything like that. I am using [PetaPoco library](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco) for database calls. All the calls are synchronous. I checked the library's relevant code too and found that the connection is closed on calls such as Query, Execute by the library itself. Then I set max connection pool size to 1 on connection string and tested the app. But no TimeoutException or slow response issue.
Can connection blocking due to sync operation happen if the app is not under heavy load?

Comment: In addition, the delay is always kind of fixed at around 14 seconds.

Comment: you'd better instrument the app (using application insights) try to figure where is the botleneck / why it's hanging

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I already have done that and saw that operations are taking too long. Because it is waiting to get a connection. Application Insights profiling showed me the same thing too. The SqlClient is waiting get a connection. But this does not happen outside App Service Environment.

Comment: You need to implement connection resiliency for Azure SQL, if you haven't already done so. There are a raft of error codes returned by a connection open with Azure SQL that indicate a retry is required. Connections aren't quite as deterministic as they are with on-premise database servers. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-connectivity-issues for more details.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole Thanks for the link. But I am not getting any errors. There is just delay to get connection. The retry count and retry interval of my app's database connection string is also unchanged from default values. So, even if there was an error and the SqlClient retried immediately, then it shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds, right? But the delay I am seeing is around 14 seconds.

Comment: I just noticed that MARS is enabled on the connection strings. Does MARS enabled connections have overhead and latency to response?

Comment: 14 seconds is not unheard of to me.

Answer (score 0):

Retry the SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance connection or establish the connection again depending on the following:

· **A transient error occurs during a connection try**

After a delay of several seconds, retry the connection.

· **A transient error occurs during a SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance query command**

Do not immediately retry the command. Instead, after a delay, **freshly establish** the connection. Then retry the command.

### Interval increase between retries

You need to wait for 5 seconds before your first retry. Retrying after a delay shorter than 5 seconds risks overwhelming the cloud service. For each subsequent retry, the delay should grow exponentially, up to a maximum of 60 seconds.

The blocking period for clients that use ADO.NET, Refer [Connection pooling (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

Set a maximum number of retries before the program has self-terminates.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-connectivity-issues)  for troubleshoot common **SQL** connectivity issues

As you are using MARS in your SQL server it is a **sequence** execution that cannot affect the connection behavior.

### Connection pooling in MARS

MARS-enabled connections are pooled like any other connection. If an application opens two connections, one with MARS enabled and one with MARS disabled, the two connections are in separate pools.

With a MARS connection, a default execution environment is associated with a connection. Every execution under a given connection receives a copy of the default environment. Once execution finishes, the execution settings are copied into the default environment.

Refer  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/enable-multiple-active-result-sets?view=sql-server-ver15) for enable/Disable Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)

Comment: I actually don't get many transient errors. The problem I am facing is around 14 seconds of delay to establish connection to SQL Server. I had thought about the retry delay, but I have not set the connect retry value in connection string. So, the value should be default. So, even with the immediate retry, it shouldn't take that long to establish connections, right? And also this delay only happens on App Service Environment. I hosted the same app outside App Service Environment, but on a basic App Service plan. The delay is in milliseconds there.

Comment: still, the issue persists?

Comment: I found that the delay was due to high DNS latency between the ASE and the Azure SQL DB. My teammates with Azure networking experience are looking into it.